# Pyspark and Python - Column is not iterable

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Python-3 with Azure data bricks.

I have a dataframe. The column 'BodyJson' is a json string that contains one occurrence of 'vmedwifi/' within it. I have added a constant string literal of 'vmedwifi/' as column named 'email_type'.

I want to find the start position of text 'vmedwifi/' with column 'BodyJson' - all columns are within the same dataframe. My code is below.

**I get the error 'Column is not iterable' on the second line of code. Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?**

```
# Weak logic to try and identify email addressess 
emailDf  = inputDf.select('BodyJson').where("BodyJson like('%vmedwifi%@%.%')").withColumn('email_type', lit('vmedwifi'))


b=emailDf.withColumn('BodyJson_Cutdown', substring(emailDf.BodyJson, expr('locate(emailDf.email_type, emailDf.BodyJson)'), 20))



TypeError: Column is not iterable
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-536715104422314> in <module>()
     12 #emailDf1  = inputDf.select('BodyJson').where("BodyJson like('%@xxx.abc.uk%')")
     13 
---> 14 b=emailDf.withColumn('BodyJson_Cutdown', substring(emailDf.BodyJson, expr('locate(emailDf.email_type, emailDf.BodyJson)'), 20))
     15 
     16 #inputDf.unpersist()
```

Comment: looks like [locate](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.locate) takes the first param as string, and second param as Column, while you passing Columns to both of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the literial passed to expr.

I decided to tackle this problem a different way which got around this issue.